# Intranet Facebook Application for updating status

Tags: facebook, intranet

I'm writing an in house intranet application which needs to update our Facebook status. (I'm new to FB development so please go easy) I don't want this application to be visible to anyone - the updates will occur via a call to the API (using the FB C# sdk) - I'm currently running in dev/sandbox mode and it's all working but is there a simpler way i can update FB status' without having to create an app in FB and authenticate etc. with OAuth? This has to be done via a web application as we have an internal review process that needs to take place on the status content then posted via an app when someone who knows the Facebook access details logs in via the app itself.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're already doing it the best/only way which will work for that use-case